# The Roman Crypto

Tags: cipher, logic-grid

This was found engraved into a stone in Roman times:
[image: ukoduS]

And underneath, an inscription:

> eoofrddene·en.do·xfrtfscqqiiut·iucraeiuioceaarriocsrt·s·ieaei,imt·oesa·serism?·,·

Even with only this minimal information, I'm sure you will be able to answer one simple question:

**Who wrote it?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Who wrote it?

> **Catullus**

Solution:

> 1. The numbers on the Roman stone form a Sudoku.  Solve it.
>  2. The inscription underneath consists of 81 symbols. Bring it into a 9x9 square.
>  3. Match the occurrences of "I" in the sudoku with the corresponding letters in the 9x9 inscription square. Read them one by one, from top to bottom. This yields "odi.et.am".
>  4. Do the same for the occurrences of "II". This yields "o.quare.i".
>  5. Repeat for III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX.

The resulting sentence is

> odi.et.amo.quare.id.faciam,fortasse.requiris?nescio,sed.fieri.sentio.et.excrucior
>  respectively:
>  **"Odi et amo. quare id faciam, fortasse requiris? nescio, sed fieri sentio et excrucior."**
>  This is the famous poem 85 by Catullus.

Comment: Very well done :)

Comment: @Tryth: the puzzle was a pleasure to solve. every step was kind of logical, but not at all easy to find.